# How to reset the navigation state properly?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

So basically here's what's going on, I have **two** navigation flows:

1. **Products flow**: I have a `StackNavigator` with two screens, the first rendering a list of all products in the stock, clicking on one product item would take you to the **details screen** as expected.
2. **Admin flow**: I have another `StackNavigator` where I'm rendering user products, basically the products that were added by the user (admin) into the stock, he can also add new products, delete, edit existing products. Any changes made by the user to his own products will be reflected in the **products flow** also since the global state will be updated.

**Note:** The two flows are conntected and accessible using a `DrawerNavigator`.

#### My issue

When the user opens the **details screen** after clicking on one of his own products and then navigates to the **admin flow** and deletes that product, I get an on error in the details screen because it's trying to render a javascript object that doesn't exist anymore which of course makes perfect sense.

#### My solution

So I figured since this error occurs only when the **details screen** has been already opened, meaning it's already in the navigation state's history, Im attempting to solve the problem by checking if the **details screen** is present in the `routes` array each time the delete button is clicked, if it's present, meaning the screen is loaded in memory, I try resetting the navigation state by keeping the previous state as it is and simply filtering out the **details screen** from the previous `routes` array and setting the new array as the new `routes` property.

Here's the code that attempts to reset the navigation state each time the delete button is clicked

```js
navigation.dispatch(state => {
                    const routes = state.routes.filter(
                      route => route.name !== 'ProductDetail',
                    );

                    return CommonActions.reset({
                      ...state,
                      routes: routes,
                    });
                  });
```

The problem is when I click on the delete button I get the following error

```js
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'action.target')
```

So where am I missing something? Any insight at all would be much apperciated.